# Tkinter - Adding images modularly

Tags: python, image, user-interface, tkinter, modularity

I'm trying to create a definition that will allow me to add images to my frame, if I pass in a valid path.

I read that i must keep an image reference from this [page](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/photoimage.htm)

Keeping that in mind I tried this in my code:

```
class tkinterHelper(Frame):

    def __init__(self, master):
        "initialize the frame"
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.grid()

    def AddImage(self, Path, X, Y):
        self.Render = PhotoImage(Path)
        TKImage = Label(self, image=self.Render)
        TKImage.image = self.Render
        TKImage.place(x=X, y=Y, relwidth=1, relheight=1)
        return self.Render

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = Tk()
    tkHelper = tkinterHelper(root)

    BackGround = tkHelper.AddImage("Images\\background.gif", 0, 0)

    root.mainloop()
```

Im was thinking that if i return `self.render` i would still have a reference to the image.

If that is not how i can keep a reference to the image, how can reference it right?

I want to keep this in the same structure it is in, because I am going to be adding a lot of images in the future to this application.

Thank You!

Comment: Your problem isn't with keeping a reference to the image, `TKImage.image = self.Render` alone probably is enough for that. You have two problems though. The first is that because of your usage of `place` and `grid`, your Frame and Label stay at size of 0. The second is that you should specify to `PhotoImage` that you're passing a file path like`self.Render = PhotoImage(file=Path)`.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the code by adding a def called `widget_placement` in my helper class

```
def widget_placement(self, widget, r, c, spacex, spacey, s):
    widget.grid(row=r, column=c, padx=spacex + 20, pady=spacey, sticky=s)
```

Then I made `def AddImage(self, path, X, Y)` return just the TKImage

```
def AddImage(self, Path, X, Y):
    self.Render = PhotoImage(file=Path)
    TKImage = Label(self, image=self.Render)
    TKImage.image = self.Render
    return TKImage
```

Lastly in my main, i put the image on the grid.

```
BackGround = tkHelper.AddImage("Images\\background.gif", 100, 100)
tkHelper.widget_placement(BackGround, 0, 0, 0, 0, W)
```